# python - Thread sleep blocks all threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I searched in other posts, but didn't find the solution of my problem.

I read content of a file and I need to do it again 20 seconds later to find if it was changed or not.

I used threading.Timer, threading.Thread with time.sleep, threading.Event with wait() and Queue - but everytime it blocks all threads, so files are not modified in the waiting period, but right after.

How can I let other function to modify the files and check for changes 20 seconds later?

Code:

```
def function1():
    counter = open('textfile.txt', 'r').read()
    result = received_msg(counter)
    return result

def received_msg(counter):
    import time
    time.sleep(20)

    with open('textfile1.txt', 'r') as c:
        newcounter = c.read()
        c.close()

        if newcounter != counter:
            with open('textfile2', 'r') as msgs:
                lines = msgs.readlines()
                msgs.close()

                if lines:
                    last_line = lines[-1]

                    return last_line

        else:
            return "No changes"
```

And here function that modifies the files:

```
def inbound():
    if request.form.get('token') == TOKEN:
        text = request.form.get('text')

        counter = open('textfile.txt', 'r').read()

        with open('textfile2.txt', 'a+') as msgs:
            msgs.write(text+'\n')
            msgs.close()

        with open('textfile.txt', 'w+') as c2:
            newcounter = int(float(counter)) + 1
            c2.write(str(newcounter))
            c2.close()

    return Response(), 200
```

Version with threading:

```
def function1():
    import threading, Queue
    q = Queue.Queue()
    counter = open('textfile.txt', 'r').read()
    threading.Timer(20, received_msg, [counter, q]).start()
    result = q.get()
    return result

def received_msg(counter):

    with open('textfile1.txt', 'r') as c:
        newcounter = c.read()
        c.close()

        if newcounter != counter:
            with open('textfile2', 'r') as msgs:
                lines = msgs.readlines()
                msgs.close()

                if lines:
                    last_line = lines[-1]

                    q.put(last_line)

        else:
            q.put("No changes")
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  Welcome to SO

Comment: `sleep` does not block all threads, actually there is no single command that does that. If this is what you are observing then the problem is somewhere else. Please post the code and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: @MaciejWolski I don't see any threading in your code.

Comment: That's one of many versions I wrote in the last hours. Just added version with threading. Thank you again for your comments.

Comment: @freakish Please look at my code. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @MaciejWolski OK, what is the purpose of `function1`? It calls `q.get()` which blocks until something's in `q`. Or maybe: what is the purpose of the queue? Or even: what you expect to happen? Basically what you've written behaves pretty much the same as single threaded version. BTW I assume that there's a typo and `received_msg` should accept `def received_msg(counter, q)`. Otherwise `received_msg` is not being called at all and thus `function1` hangs forever.

Comment: @freakish yes, I made a typo while editing. function1 is called when I need to get the last line of the text file (last message). What I do with this code? I am forwarding message to Instant Messenger where someone is writing answer. It is sent to outbound function which writes it to file. But with my code the answer is saved after waiting period and is not read by received_msg. So q.get is blocking... I do not know what approach would make it possible to send message and wait 20 sec for reply in text file, saved meanwhile by other function.